# Reading input string from a text file in progress4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a .txt file having some text. I want to read this file and store it into a string.
Is there available any function for that?
Or how to do it ? please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
define variable s as longchar no-undo.

copy-lob from file "fileName.txt" to s.
```

Answer (score 2):

DEF VAR ch-var AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

INPUT FROM VALUE(file-name).

REPEAT:

IMPORT UNFORMATTED ch-var.

END.

Comment: Caution if the file is not properly terminated you will end up missing last line or duplicate line.https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000056072